# When can we reduce "while clause" as in "don't eat lying down" and "don't talk facing the fan"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, adverbials

It seems like native speakers say "**don't eat lying down**" and "**don't talk facing the fan**" when they mean "**don't eat while lying down**" and "**don't talk while facing the fan**" respectively.

But in some other situations, we can not do the same things,

For example,

“**Don't drink while driving**” is ok, but “**Don't drink driving**” is not ok.

"**I saw an accident while I was walking down the street**" is ok, but "**I saw an accident walking down the street**" is not ok.

When can we reduce "**while clause**"?

Comment: Well, part of an answer lies with the avoidance of ambiguity and the unintended turning of something serious into something funny.  "I saw an accident walking down the road" is a bit weird, while "I saw a snake..." or ... a corpse walking down the road" become silly because of the alternative grammatical construction.

Comment: The following question is about past participial phrases rather than present participial phrases, but most sources seem to treat them together. Basically, put a comma in if they're at the end of a sentence and not connected to the preceding word. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202299/comma-before-a-participial-phrase

Comment: It's true that *I saw an accident walking down the street* sounds a bit "off", but that's just because the participial clause looks like a dangling participle erroneously attaching to "accident" rather than to the entire preceding text. With minor resequencing, *Walking down the street, I saw an accident* is absolutely fine.

Comment: From an answer to a relevant ELL question: [***while** is optional when one of the actions is already in progress and the first action is not the cause of the second, even though it may be related to it*.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/97588/126)